# Solving $\dot x=\frac{x+\sqrt{t^2+x^2}}{t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

> I want to solve $\dot x=\frac{x+\sqrt{t^2+x^2}}{t}$ with initial value $x(1)=0$.

My plan was to substitute and then use separation of variables but I think I am misunderstanding something about substitution:

Let's set $u:=x/t$. Then $$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{t}\frac{dx}{dt}.$$ So the equation $\dot x=\frac{x+\sqrt{t^2+x^2}}{t}$ should transform to $$t\frac{du}{dt}=u+\sqrt{1+u^2}.$$ By separation of variables I would now need to solve the integral $$\int\frac{du}{u+\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$ which doesn't seem right to me. Did something go wrong along the way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is not correct
$$\frac{du}{dt}=\frac{du}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{t}\frac{dx}{dt}.$$
$x,t$ are functions of t so when you differentiate you get :
$$u'=\frac {du}{dt}=\frac d{dt}\left(\frac {x(t)} t\right)= \frac{x't-x}{t^2}  \implies x'=u't+u$$
Since you have u as a function of two functions of t
$$u(t)=f(t)g(t) \implies u'(t)=f'g+fg'$$
where $f=x(t)$ and $g(t)=1/t$
$$\dot x=\frac{x+\sqrt{t^2+x^2}}{t}$$
$$ \implies u't+u=\frac{ut+\sqrt{t^2+t^2u^2}}{t}$$
$$  u't=\frac {|t|}t{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$
It's separable
$$  \int \frac {du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=\int \frac {dt}{|t|}$$
As @Dylan pointed out due to the initial condition $t$ being positive we can write
$$  \int \frac {du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}=\int \frac {dt}{t}$$

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: yw @Buh  the substitution is good just a little mistake when you took the derivative.

Comment: The initial condition is at $t=1$ so you can write $|t|=t$, but (+1) for being rigorous

Comment: Oh you are completely right @Dylan... t is positive due to the initial condition..  I added a line